# Sudoku Game with automatically generated Sudokus

Tags: javascript, sudoku

#### Project

I've created a puzzle site with automatically generated sudokus.

For more information on Sudokus, please see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku).

#### The code

```js
const GRID_SIZE = 9;
const REMOVE = 50;

let solution = createArray(9, 9);

let textIsVisible = false;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    initialize();
});

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    let k = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            let value = parseInt(elements[k].value);
            if(value !== solution[i][j]) {
                textIsVisible = true;
                $('#text').text('That\'s not the correct solution!');
                return;
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
    textIsVisible = true;
    $('#text').text('Correct!');
});

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', function() {
    initialize();
});

function initialize() {
    textIsVisible = false;
    $('#text').text('');
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.add('focus');
        elements[i].removeAttribute('readonly');
        elements[i].classList.remove('bold');
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            $('#text').text('');
        });
    }
    let sudoku = generate();
    solveSudoku(sudoku, 0);
    showSudoku(elements, sudoku);
}

function generate() {
    //Fill with zeros
    let sudoku = createArray(9, 9);
    for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            sudoku[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    //Add ten random numbers
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sudoku = addNumber(sudoku);
    }

    /*
     * Add random numbers in the first row in addition to random numbers
     * in addition to random numbers on random positions
     */
    sudoku[0][1] = legalNumbers(sudoku, 0, 1);
    sudoku[0][4] = legalNumbers(sudoku, 0, 4);
    sudoku[0][7] = legalNumbers(sudoku, 0, 7);


    //Solve sudoku
    solveSudoku(sudoku, 0);
    for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            sudoku[i][j] = solution[i][j];
        }
    }

    /*
     * Remove elements so that sudoku still has unique solution
     */
    let i = 0;
    while(i < REMOVE) {
        let row = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        let col = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        if(sudoku[row][col] !== 0) {
            let cache = sudoku[row][col];
            sudoku[row][col] = 0;
            if(solveSudoku(sudoku, 0) !== 1) {
                /*
                 * Go one step back if sudoku doesn't have unique solution
                 * anymore
                 */
                sudoku[row][col] = cache;
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return sudoku;
}

function createArray(rows, cols) {
    const array = new Array(rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        array[i] = new Array(cols);
    }
    return array;
}

function addNumber(sudoku) {
    /*
     * Find random position to add number
     */
    let row = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    let col = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

    /*
     * Add random, but legal number
     */
    sudoku[row][col] = legalNumbers(sudoku, row, col);
    return sudoku;
}

function solveSudoku(sudoku, count) {
    for(let i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {
            /*
             * Only empty fields will be changd
             */
            if(sudoku[i][j] === 0) {
                /*
                 * Try all numbers between 1 and 9
                 */
                for(let n = 1; n <= GRID_SIZE && count < 2; n++) {
                    /*
                     * Is number n safe?
                     */
                    if(checkRow(sudoku, i, n) && checkColumn(sudoku, j, n) && checkBox(sudoku, i, j, n)) {
                        sudoku[i][j] = n;
                        let cache = solveSudoku(sudoku, count);
                        /*
                         * new solution found
                         */
                        if(cache > count) {
                            count = cache;
                            /*
                             * Save new solution
                             */
                            for(let k = 0; k < GRID_SIZE; k++) {
                                for(let l = 0; l < GRID_SIZE; l++) {
                                    if(sudoku[k][l] !== 0) {
                                        solution[k][l] = sudoku[k][l];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            sudoku[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                        /*
                         * Not a solution, go one step back
                         */
                        else {
                            sudoku[i][j] = 0;
                        }

                    }
                }
                /*
                 * No other solution found
                 */
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * found another solution
     */
    return count + 1;
}

function showSudoku(elements, sudoku) {
    let k = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {
            if(sudoku[i][j] > 0) {
                elements[k].value = sudoku[i][j];
                elements[k].setAttribute('readonly', 'true');
                elements[k].classList.remove('focus');
                elements[k].classList.add('bold');
            }
            else {
                elements[k].value = '';
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
}


/*
 * Helper functions
 */

function checkRow(sudoku, row, n) {
    for(let i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        if(sudoku[row][i] === n) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkColumn(sudoku, col, n) {
    for(let i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        if(sudoku[i][col] === n) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkBox(sudoku, row, col, n) {
    row = row - row % 3;
    col = col - col % 3;
    for(let i = row; i < row + 3; i++) {
        for(let j = col; j < col + 3; j++) {
            if(sudoku[i][j] === n) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function legalNumbers(sudoku, row, col) {
    let array = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if(checkRow(sudoku, row, i) && checkColumn(sudoku, col, i) && checkBox(sudoku, row, col, i)) {
            array.push(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function isNumber(elem, e) {
    if(elem.value.length !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    let id = e.key;
    let string = '123456789';
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if(string.charAt(i) === id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fonts/baloo/stylesheet.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fonts/open-sans/stylesheet.css'>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='logo.svg'/>
    <script src='jquery.js'></script>
    <title>Sudoku</title>
    <style>
        /*
         * Font sizes
         */
        html {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 1.8em;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 1.42em;
        }

        /*
         * 'Fork me on GitHub'-image
         */
        #fork {
            position: absolute;
            width: 160px;
            height: 160px;
            top: 0;
            border: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        /*
         * Main style
         */
        body {
            font-family: 'open-sans',sans-serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.65;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .inner {
            width: 350px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        /*
         * Sudoku field container
         */
        .sudoku {
            line-height: 34px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .mainContainer {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .container {
            line-height: 36px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: 'balooregular', serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #00410B;
        }

        /*
         * Input fields main style
         */
        input {
            border: none;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1em;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
            border-right: 2px solid black;
            border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        }

        /*
         * Don't show arrow buttons inside input fields
         */
        input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
        input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
            display: none;
        }

        input[type=number] {
            -moz-appearance:textfield;
        }

        input:focus, button:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        /*
         * Input field additional border styles
         */
        .left {
            border-left: 2px solid black;
        }

        .right {
            border-right: 2px solid red;
        }

        .top {
            border-top: 2px solid black;
        }

        .bottom {
            border-bottom: 2px solid red;
        }


        /*
         * Given numbers will be bold
         */
        .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        /*
         * Fields that user has to fill out
         * will be LightGray on focus
         */
        .focus:focus {
            background: LightGray;
        }

        /*
         * Style of buttons
         */
        button {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 40%;
            text-align: center;
            transition: 0.3s ease;
            margin: 20px 5% 30px;
            float: left;
        }

        button:hover {
            color: #FFFFF0;
            background: #00410B;
        }

        /*
         * links
         */
        a {
            color: #2B823A;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        /*
         * Responsive
         */

        @media (max-width: 650px) {
            #fork {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 350px) {
            html {
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            .inner {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 330px) {
            .sudoku {
                line-height: 24px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .container {
                line-height: 26px;
            }

            input {
                border: none;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 1em;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                float: left;
                border-right: 2px solid black;
                border-bottom: 2px solid black;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='https://github.com/philippwilhelm/Sudoku' id='fork'><img alt='' src='fork.png'></a>
    <div class='inner'>
        <h1>Sudoku</h1>
        <div class='sudoku'>
            <div class='mainContainer'>
                <div class='container'>
                    <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='left top'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='top'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right top'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft top'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='top'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right top'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft top'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='top'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='top'/><br>
                </div>
                <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='left'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><br>
                <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom left'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom'/><br>
                <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='left'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><br>
                <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='left'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><br>
                <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom left'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='bottom'/><br>
                <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='left'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><br>
                <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='left'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><br>
                <input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='left'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='right'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class='notLeft'/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><input maxlength='1' onkeypress='return isNumber(this, event)' type='number' min='0' max='9' value='0'  class=''/><br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button id='submit'>Submit</button><button id='reset'>New Game</button>

        <span id='text'></span>
        <script src='sudoku_generator.js'></script>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Question

All suggestions are welcome. The html-file only is a minimal working example, so it is not really worth reviewing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Always use `const` when possible** - only use `let` when you [want to warn other readers of the code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) that the variable name may be reassigned. If something won't be reassigned, make it clear to readers that they don't have to worry about that by using `const` instead of `let`.

**Anonymous callback wrappers around a single function are superfluous**, at least in almost all cases - just pass the *single function* as the callback instead (see below).

**Prefer DOMContentLoaded over `load`** - `load` waits for *all resources* to completely finish downloading, including possibly heavyweight images. Better to make the page interactive as soon as the DOM is populated, instead of waiting for sub-resources to finish.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize);
```

Or, since you're using jQuery, you could also do:

```
$(initialize);
```

**jQuery or vanilla DOM methods?** At the moment, you're using jQuery for *only one purpose* - to call `.text`, to set the text of elements. This is odd: jQuery is a big library, and element text can be set easily by simply using `textContent`, no library required. If you *do* want to make this into a jQuery project (which I wouldn't recommend, since it doesn't seem to be accomplishing anything useful at the moment), it would be more stylistically consistent to use jQuery whenever you're using DOM manipulation.

**`textIsVisible` doesn't do anything** You reference it 4 times, but always to *assign* to it, never to *read* from it - might as well remove it entirely.

**Prefer array methods and iterators** over `for` loops that require manual iteration and have no abstraction. For example, given:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.add('focus');
    // do lots of other stuff with elements[i]
```

Unless you need to use the index somewhere other than to reference `elements[i]`, it would make more sense to write [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and more abstract code with an iterator. It's shorter too:

```
for (const element of elements) {
    element.classList.add('focus');
    // do lots of other stuff with element
```

Aleksei's answer shows how to use array methods with other parts of the code too.

**Condense class names** Since the cells will always have exactly 1 of 2 classes, `focus` or `bold`, consider using just a single class instead that you toggle on and off - perhaps `focus`. For example, instead of:

```
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

use

```
.container > input {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

whose rules get overridden by a `.container > .focus` rule below.

**Don't reassign a variable to the same object you already have a reference to**. That is:

```
sudoku = addNumber(sudoku);
```

should be

```
addNumber(sudoku);
```

**Use comments to describe why, or what *if* what isn't obvious** - for example:

```
// Go one step back if sudoku doesn't have unique solution anymore
```

is good, whereas

```
//Solve sudoku
solveSudoku(sudoku, 0);
```

doesn't communicate anything useful.

**solveSudoku** is somewhat confusing: it returns a value that often isn't used by callers, and reassigns the solution into a variable completely disconnected from the caller. For example:

```
let sudoku = generate();
solveSudoku(sudoku, 0);
showSudoku(elements, sudoku);
```

The purpose of `solveSudoku` is mysterious until you read the function to find out what its side-effects are. Functions are easiest to make sense of at a glance when they're pure, or at least not too impure. Here, consider *returning the value* from `solveSudoku` and using it, eg:

```
const sudoku = generate();
solution = solveSudoku(sudoku, 0).solution; // with `numUniqueSolutions` as the other property in the object
showSudoku(elements, sudoku);
```

That makes a lot more sense at a glance. You could go further and avoid the reassignment of the `solution` variable at all, but that would require some significant refactoring.

The above approach also makes it much clearer what sort of value `solveSudoku` is returning: `numUniqueSolutions` (This isn't obvious at a glance from your current implementation of `solveSudoku`)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest writing code in functional style instead of excessive usage of loops. This will make your code more concise (you can reduce code for your solution by half) and readable. I rewrote a few of your functions to give an idea of what I mean:

```
const range = (from, to) => [...Array(to - from + 1).keys()].map((i) => i + from);

const checkRow = (sudoku, row, n) => range(0, GRID_SIZE - 1).every((x) => sudoku[row][x] !== n);
const checkColumn = (sudoku, col, n) => range(0, GRID_SIZE - 1).every((x) => sudoku[x][col] !== n);

const combine = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.reduce((result, x) => result.concat(arr2.map((y) => [x, y])), []);

const boxCells = (row, col) => {
    row = row - row % 3;
    col = col - col % 3;
    return combine(range(row, row + 2), range(col, col + 2));
}

const checkBox = (sudoku, row, col, n) => boxCells(row, col).every(([r, c]) => sudoku[r][c] !== n);

const legalNumbers = (sudoku, row, col) => {
    const valid = (x) => checkRow(sudoku, row, x) && checkColumn(sudoku, col, x) && checkBox(sudoku, row, col, x);
    return range(1, 9).find(valid);
}

const isNumber = (elem, { key }) => elem.value === '' && '123456789'.split('').includes(key);
```